# How to post push notifications in APNS and how to show the notifications in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have several doubts about APNS. Am trying myself to make clear on the APNS but still need some clarifications. I have to know `how we are posting push notification in APN Server and how we push the notification to Apple APN Server?` And also how am i receive the notification from Apple and show the notification to user? I know we are receive the Notifications from below delegate,

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

`How we should show the notifications to the user`, please suggest any sample codes? Please clarify my silly doubts. Thanks in advance. Please help me.

Comment: From here you can take a cue to proceed: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this tutorial is useful please see
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

when you receive push notificaion ,please `NSLog userInfo`

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
      NsLog("%@",userInfo);
}
```

push notificaion  is come only one time , pop is open for about 10 second(Depend on notifcation type)... if you click then didReceiveRemoteNotification delegte  is call , if you can't click any reason you see notificaion by go to setting->notification click...and check

if you want store total push notifaction use the database and store in your database